# Using a method as part of key:value

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a javascript file that is generating my interface (border container and content panes with content) I call this method (_requestGraphs) to send a request and I am trying to call a method that calculates my epoch time (the function calclateEpoch()) that I use throughout my application.

```
_requestGraphs: function (param1, param2){
var context = this;
request:{
   Clusters: "",
   Servers: "",
   StartTime: context._calculatEpoch(param2), //generate epoch time
   EndTime: epochNow,
   Width: 400,
   Height: 120,
},
}).then(function (response) {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: Take a look at here to understand JSON. There are no functions in a JSON object: http://json.org/

Comment: I modified the post due to reviewers thinking this is my json file I need help with. I simply need to know if you can run a function as a value of a key